# Why aren't these shared_ptrs pointing to the same container?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a class Model:

```
class Model
{
    ...

    boost::shared_ptr<Deck>  _deck;
    boost::shared_ptr<CardStack> _stack[22];
};
```

`Deck` inherits from `CardStack`.

I tried to make `_stack[0]` point to the same thing that `_deck` points to by going:

```
{
    _deck = boost::shared_ptr<Deck>(new Deck());
    _stack[0] = _deck;
}
```

It seems that the assignment to `_deck` of `_stack[0]` results in a copy of `_deck` being made. (I know this because modifications to `_stack[0]` do not result in modifications to `_deck`.) How can I get them to point to the same thing?

Ok - no copy constructor is being called. I have verified this by implementing it and seeing if it gets called - it doesn't.

However - I have a function that operates on `CardStack` objects:

```
void TransferSingleCard(CardStack & src, CardStack & dst, Face f)
{
    if( !src._cards.empty() )
    {
        src._cards.back().SetFace(f);
        dst.PushCard(src._cards.back());
        src._cards.pop_back();
    }   

}
```

Now - when I call:

```
{
    TransferSingleCard(*_stack[DECK], _someotherplace, FACEDOWN);
    std::cout << *_stack[DECK];
    std::cout << *_deck;
}
```

I get this output (where std::cout on a `CardStack` will print out the size of that stack):

```
Num(103) TOP
Num(104) TOP
```

... so I've concluded (incorrectly?) that `_stack[DECK]` points to something different.

The Deck

```
class Deck : public CardStack
{
public:
    Deck(int numsuits=2, StackIndex index = NO_SUCH_STACK );
    Deck::Deck( const Deck & d);
    int DealsLeft() const;
    void RecalcDealsLeft();
private:
    int _dealsleft;
};
```

Comment: That should work. What error do you get or how do you know that a copy is being made.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - I know that it's a copy, because I modify `_stack[0]` (it's basically a container for `Card` objects) by pulling `Card` objects out of it. Then I query them both - `_stack[0]` is down in size as expected, but `_deck` is still the same size as before the pull.

Comment: Have you tried to make both `shared_ptr` of the same type? Can you show what modifications you make? Also, try implementing a copy-constructor and see if it gets called (it should't). Can you show the `Deck` and `CardStack` classes?

Comment: What is `DECK`?  Are you sure `_stack[DECK]` and `_deck` refer to the same object?  You initially said that `_stack[0]` and `_deck` were the same, but now you've got a new variable.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose - yes. Sorry, I was using 0 for convenience. The code actually uses the call `_stack[DECK] = _deck;`, where `DECK` is defined in an enum as 0. It does this assignment during the `Model` constructor. I haven't printed out addresses for the two pointers yet, but I don't see any other assignments to `_stack[DECK]` or `_deck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example - derives from @Neil's answer, tries to emulate what you say is happening. Could you check that it works as expected (A and B have the same count) on your system.

Then we could try and modify this code or your code until they match.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    virtual ~A()
    {
        std::cerr << "Delete A" << std::endl;
    }
    int _count;
    void decrement()
    {
        _count --;
    }
};
class B : public A {
    public:
    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cerr << "Delete B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B);
    b->_count = 104;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a;
    a = b;

    a->decrement();

    std::cerr << "A:" << a->_count << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "B:" << b->_count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

So from the comment, we know the original pointers are correct, so now we need to trace.

Either:

1. log pointers to see when they change.
2. Use watchpoints in a debugger to see when the pointer changes.
3. Use a third shared pointer to see which pointer is changed.
4. Introduce a function that changes both pointers at the same time.

Comment: Well, I went back to basics and your code proves that they do indeed *start off* pointing to the same thing. The `TransferSingleCard()` even works - the size is the same. However, further down the line, the `TransferSingleCard()` gives me different results for each pointer.

Comment: I guess that means that one of the pointers is getting changed - I suggest logging the pointer address each time you print out the size, and see when they get changed.

Comment: Yes you're right. The `_deck` pointer was getting reset to something else via `boost::shared_ptr::reset()`. I think I had assumed that `reset()` wouldn't change the address of `_deck` (not sure why in retrospect), and that `_stack[DECK]` would not have to change also. Anyway - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what you are asking about - consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual ~A() {
        cout << "destroyed" << endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A {
};

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b( new B );
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a;
    a = b;
}
```

Only one "destroy" message appears, indicating that no copy has been made.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the problem is that you're assigning between different types here. `boost::shared_ptr` is a template and templates are not polymorphic even if the type in them is. So what's happening is that your compiler sees the assignment from `boost::shared_ptr<Deck>` to `boost::shared_ptr<CardStack>` and notices that it can make the assignment by calling the copy constructor for CardStack to duplicate the Deck object.

I think what you want the assignment to look like is something like this:

```
_stack[0] = boost::static_pointer_cast<CardStack>(_deck);
```

Which will do the conversion the way you expect it to.

Comment: @BeeBand - I just noticed you updated the question and you've verified that it doesn't call the copy constructor. In that case the above technique won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want `shared_array` for `_stack`  . . . Take a look at the documentation on `shared_ptr`;from boost.org, specifically:

> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm
>
> "Normally, a shared_ptr cannot
>   correctly hold a pointer to a
>   dynamically allocated array. See
>   shared_array for that usage."

Also, be aware of the `T* get()` function (not to be used without good reason) which returns the raw pointer being held by the managed pointer (shared_ptr in this case).

Comment: `CardStack` is basically a wrapper around a `std::deque<Card>`. Does `shared_array` still apply?

Comment: It does if you have a shared_ptr to an array in your code.  I may have misunderstood . . .